# Where can I find the log output when debugging locally?

Tags: .net, logging, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying out the new Azure mobile services .Net backend. When debugging locally - where can I find the log output? Is it configurable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs go to the regular .NET system diagnostics. To see them you can add a trace listener to your web.config, and you'll see the traces going to the file you specify. For an example, see the snippet below.

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="default"
           type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="c:\temp\trace.log" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```